# Can ECG electrodes be used for EEG detection?

Tags: electrical, biopotential, electrically-conductive, ecg, eeg

Im having financial limitation for purchasing EEG monitoring modules or electrodes. But so is not the case for ECG. I am doubtful whether I can use ECG electrodes for EEG since brainwaves are in the order of micro while ECG are much higher . On the hand I  have searched and found some sites claiming that this is possible.
Can someone give me a definite solution?
Also if I can use what precautions should I take?

I am planning to use these [electrodes](https://robu.in/product/ecg-module-ad8232-heart-ecg-monitoring-sensor-module-kit-arduino-2/)

Are these suitable for EEG?

Comment: Using an ECG amplifier for EEG won't work very well, for reasons you've already stated.  The electrodes, though, assuming you can get them mounted in the right place and get them to stay, should be OK -- just the geometry for mounting really differs

Comment: Your title doesn't match the question.  Are you asking about the electrodes, the amplifier, or both?

Comment: I'm asking about the electrodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither the amp nor electrodes will be very useful.

ECG pads are capacitive with large surface area and EEG must be more conductive with many probes to increase pressure points with rounded tips.

Hair will interfere with results ( poor conduction) and you will get motion voltages from galvanic voltages and variation in pressure.

Also the gain must be about 20dB higher  http://i.ebayimg.com/images/i/191441995702-0-1/s-l1000.jpg  http://www.pkfamily.com/users/solson/eeg/picAD.gif

"Right Leg drive" improves the CMRR but can use a large capacitive pad on the neck or leg.

You can fit it onto a snug open top golf cap.